# I'm trying to find this contact for a 3d printer

Tags: identification, components, contact

So one of the contacts that detect the cartridge in my 3d printer broke. I'm trying to find a similar generic contact that I can solder on. It's for a discontinued CubePro so I doubt I'll find any original parts. Where would I find this type of PCB mounted contact? Mouser.com? I'm not sure what it is called either..

Thank You!

[image: broken two prong contact that I am trying to replace or fix]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This connector type is called "spring loaded connector". You have to take care of the pin pitch. This looks like standard 2.54mm. Since the other side are copper pads the connector doesnt have to be exaclt the same. Maybe SAM12848-ND could do the thing.

Comment: Awesome! That's the kind of expertise I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to see that I could help you. Would be great if you can mark this answer as "accepted".